# Как при помощи сопрограмм (корутин) определить что функция зависла?

Tags: lua

Я вроде как уже изучил lua досконально, но последнее, чего я не понимаю - это корутины.

Передо мной сейчас стоит такая задача: мой главный скрипт подключает сторонний модуль, который работает в защищённом окружении. Злоумышленник не может сделать ничего плохого из этого модуля, потому что ему не доступны никакие функции или переменные. Но единственная пакость, которую он может устроить - это зависнуть: `while true do end`. По этому я должен обернуть функцию сопрограммой c таймером, который просто отсчитывает пару секунд и если за это время функция ещё не завершилась - убить её и выбросить ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: если злоумышленник может писать код - это уже проблема... В вашем случае, думаю, можно запустить это скрипт в отдельном потоке, который будет проверяться по прошествии определенного времени и если он еще не завершил выполнение скрипта, то завершаете поток принудительно. Как-то так

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо за эту мысль, но можно подробнее? Чем корутины плохи для такой задачи и почему вы считаете это проблемой? По-моему обычное дело. Код злоумышленник особо писать не может, потому что ему не доступны **совсем** никакие переменные, даже **_G**. Он банально `print('hello')` не может. Всё что я ему разрешил - это передать мне таблицу с настройками, которую я дальше разбираю сам.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у меня сейчас нет времени углублённо изучить коорутины, но как только я его найду, обязательно отвечу на свой вопрос, если никто не сделает этого раньше меня. Но если вы уверены что корутины для такой задачи не подходят и лучше заменить их параллельными потоками, то я поверю вам на слово и буду благодарен за сэкономленное время, но хотелось бы услышать хоть какие-то аргументы :)

Comment: я что-то не пойму: во-первых про корутины я вообще ничего не говорил, даже слово такого не упоминал. Во-вторых, если вам необходимо передать только таблицу с настройками, без необходимости писать код, то почему вы используете lua для этого? Проще просто использовать json, xml или что-то подобное

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch мой вопрос о том, как решить проблему при помощи корутин. Вы предложили другой вариант, который в целом приемлим, так же как и другие форматы, но оба варианта плохо подходят для приложения, которое написано на чистом lua. Во-первых зачем мне парсить сторонние форматы, если я могу подключить родную таблицу? Во-вторых я хочу оформить свой код в виде библиотеки на luarocks (основное назначение которой - использование lua вместо json и xml) и в этом случае решить задачу через многопоточность просто невозможно, потому что в стандартных средствах lua её нет.

Comment: то что вы хотите невозможно решить с помощью корутин и прочих средств языка просто потому что ваша задача - ограничить средства языка. Поэтому я и предлагаю решение без использования языка программирования. Тобишь решить проблему концептуально, а не програмно. Конечно, можно еще решить и с потоками, внедрив lua скрипт в программу на c/c++, но если вам и это не подходит, то остается только один вариант: написать свой собственный парсер, который будет проверять отсутсвие конструкций, которые вы хотите избежать. PS не понимаю почему вы привязались к корутинам

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вы недооцениваете гибкость lua. Ограничение средств языка средствами языка - это обычная фича lua, которая называется [sandboxing](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) и Роберто ни раз упоминал о ней на презентациях. Ваше предложение справедливо, но я не уверен что оно лучшее в моей ситуации.

Comment: мы с вами говорим немного на разных языках: сандбоксы это конечно хорошо, но в любом сандбоксе вы сможете использовать все ключевые слова языка (например while). Если же в "сандбоксе" у вас недоступны ключевые слова, или они выполняют другую функцию - это уже другой язык. И нет, в lua нельзя стандартными средствами изменить использование ключевых слов

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch конечно нельзя. Я не очень точно выразился. Под средствами языка я имел ввиду только глобальную область и все базовые переменные, но не ключевые слова, и этот вопрос я задал именно потому что хочу узнать, нельзя ли запустить мою сэнбокс-функцию в корутине и убить её через пару секунд, если её статус is 'running', для того чтобы обойти невозможность ограничить while. Потому что while - это единственное ключевое слово, которое создаёт небольшую проблему (в принципе, зависание программы при подключении стороннего конфига - это не очень страшно и ничему не повредит, но всё же).

Comment: отвечая на вышеприведенный вопрос: нет, нельзя. И это касается не только корутин (чего вы к ним привязались?). В вашем случае лучший вариант: это конфиг без lua, вариант с потоками что я предлагал - хуже, а вариант с парсером - сложнее

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch хорошо, спасибо. Я привязался к ним потому что они моя последняя надежда :D, но если действительно нельзя, то я просто закрою глаза на while, потому что мне не нравится идея с парсингом всяких xml. Это медленно и не нативно.

Comment: не медленне чем интерпретация скрипта

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch 10000 чтений файла через io.open и последующего разбора через dkjson у меня заняли 0.403 секунды, а столько же загрузок через loadfile 0.324 секунды. Так что медленнее, хотя разница и мизерная.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch хотя нет, всё же не мизерная. Она сильно зависит от размера файла. Я увеличил тестовые файлы с трёх до десяти строк и разница уже 0.817 к 0.427! Уверен что при сотнях строк разница будет в десятки раз.

Comment: во-первых: объем файла меряется не количеством строк а байтами. Во-вторых, dkjson написар на lua - вы что думали, что он будет очень быстрый? Используйте cjson если вам нужна скорость - он написан на Си. В-третьих, при таких замерах указывайте как он проводился - способ и данные могут сильно влиять на результат?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch какая разница в чём они меряются? Я лишь убедился в том что парсинг медленнее интерпретации, а детали меня не интересуют. Если я сейчас начну приводить все данные, то нас с вами забанят на этом сайте за то что мы общаемся километрами текста здесь, а не в чате. В любом случае, это уже совсем другая тема. Я не хочу её обсуждать лишь потому что меня не интересует сам формат json. Я хочу хранить данные в lua, а json пусть используют те, кому нравится javascript.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch хорошо, cjson быстрее - 0.311 к 0.418.

Comment: что и требовалось доказать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я согласен со всем, что написал @AndrejLevkovitch в комментариях – коорутины в данном случае не помогут.

Решения у данной задачи два: если у вас в приоритете производительность, то используйте что-нибудь вроде [cjson](https://github.com/openresty/lua-cjson).

Если же хотите использовать родные lua-таблицы, то сгодится любой сериализатор, например [lume.deserialize](https://github.com/rxi/lume#lumedeserializestr). Он работает не медленнее интерпретатора, но не быстрее чем cjson.

Comment: Незачем тащить в луа интерпретатор чужих форматов, когда сам луа создавался с целью быть основным языком для файлов конфигураций.  Храните всё в виде луа-кода.  Чтобы избежать зависания, вешайте хук и срубайте скрипт из хука, когда отработаны 10000 инструкций.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff согласен, не зачем. Но во-первых - назначение lua гораздо шире и с такой целью он не создавался; во-вторых - хранить конфиги в виде чистого lua не безопасно (ровно как и в js никто не хранит конфиги в формате js, для этого был создано json). А сэндбоксинг уступает по надёжности сериализации. Я не представляю, как именно средствами чистого lua вы будете вешать хук. Можно пример?

Comment: про хуки читайте мануал.  сэндбоксинг в луа - очень легко реализуем.  про то, для чего создавался луа, читайте статьи автора луа, особенно про наследие языка "сол", на базе которого был создан луа.  а если вы мыслите про луа как про какой-то аналог JS - то вы просто ещё не поняли суть луа.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff причём здесь JS? Это касается всех языков. Никто не пишет скрипты в конфигах. У луа нет никакой "сути". Я использую его как правило в качестве самостоятельного языка, хотя большинство людей его встраивают. Оба применения имеют полное право на существование. Я рассматриваю lua как максимально гибкий язык, а не как созданный для определённых целей. Таким он и является.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff на счёт хуков - никогда ими не пользовался, как-нибудь попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff касательно самого вопроса - наверное вы правы, можно реализовать всё в сандбоксе, но я замерял скорость сандбокса и десерериализации и разница была ничтожно мизерной, причём даже не в пользу сандбокса. Так что в принципе конечно можно заморочиться, но особо смысла нет.

Comment: `Никто не пишет скрипты в конфигах.` - вы удивитесь, но именно для этого был создан луа )))

Comment: небольшой исторический ликбез.  есть дохрена конфиг-языков, которые могут хранить числа, строки и вложенные таблицы из чисел и строк.  Таким языком был sol.  авторам луа не хватило возможностей сола - они хотели хранить в конфигах числа, строки, таблицы и алгоритмы.  и они создали язык луа.